# Manim Brodcast animation for Arc

Tags: python, manim

I am using `manim community 0.17.2` and would like to to a `Broadcast` with a circle segment. For the circle secment I use `Arc` and that is probably just not fully compatible with `Broadcast`.

The geometry looks like this:

[image: geometry]

Where the red line is the `arc_1`. If I now do a `Broadcast(arc_1)` I get this:

[image]

The lines no not start from the circle center but from the smallest Box around the arc, shifted to the origin.

The expected result is that the lines of the animation start at the center of the cricle like this (but confined in the circle segment):

[image: circle]

This is the full example code:

```
from manim import *
from math import sqrt

class testFeature1(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        l1= Line((0,0,0),(-5/sqrt(2),-5/sqrt(2),0)).set_stroke(WHITE,4)
        l2= Line((0,0,0),(5/sqrt(2),-5/sqrt(2),0)).set_stroke(WHITE,4)
        l3= Line((-5/sqrt(2),-5/sqrt(2),0),(5/sqrt(2),-5/sqrt(2),0)).set_stroke(WHITE,4)
        self.add(l1,l2,l3)
        arc_1 = Arc(radius=5,start_angle=-3/4*PI,angle=PI/2).set_color(RED)
        self.add(arc_1)
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Broadcast(arc_1, final_opacity=0.5))
```

My ultimate goal is to have the `Broadcast` animation confined just in the white triangle. All parts which leave the triangle should be hidden. And the cherry on top would be to have the bottom line of the triangle stay red at positions which have already been hit by the `Broadcast`.